# Creating & using categorical data type with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I'm having trouble changing the type of my variable to a categorical data type.

My variable is called "Energy class" and contains the following values:
A++, A+, A, B, C, D, E, F, G.

I want to change the type to a category and order the categories in that same order.

Hence: A++ = 1, A+ = 2, A = 3, B = 4 , etc.

I will also have to perform the same manipulation with another variable, "Condition of the building", which conains the following values: "Very good, "Good", "To be restored".

I tried using the pandas `set_categories()` method. But it didn't work. There is very little information on how to use it in the documentation.

Anyone knows how to deal with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```
energy_class = {'A++':1, 'A+':2,...}
df['Energy class'] = df['Energy class'].map(energy_class)
```

A bit fancier when you have *ordered list* of the classes

```
energy_classes = ['A++', 'A+',...]
df['Energy_class'] = df['Energy class'].map(dict(**enumerate(energy_classes,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordered `pd.Categorical`:

```
df['energy_class'] = pd.Categorical(
    df['energy_class'],
    categories=['A++', 'A+', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    ordered=True)
```